# How Can I Make my ImageButton go to another activity in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imagebutton

I want to know how I can make my ImageButton to go to another activity in **Android Studio 1.2.2**?

I tried to make it using the way that was made for buttons.

**This is my Java code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_01);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_menu_01, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

  }
}
```

Comment: Declare an image button in your layout and find the object in onCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to create a ImageButton on the layout.xml of your current activity:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/your_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Than, in your current activity, you need to create a variable ImageButton:

```
ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.the_button_you_created_on_the_layout.xml_file);
```

Then, you need to set a click listener to this button:

*The click listener will "wait" for the click in your button.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListner(){
    // When the button is pressed/clicked, it will run the code below
    @Override
    public void onClick(){
        // Intent is what you use to start another activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

After that, your app should start the other activity with no problem.

Comment: When I put the javascript code says me error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<MainActivity2>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: This is my Javascript code:
                myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                       Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

Comment: You should add the new activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

<activity
            android:name=".yourNewActivty"
            android:label="Name of your activity"
            android:parentActivityName=".theActivityThatStartsThisNewOne" >

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.you.myapplication.theActivityThatStartsThisNewOne" />

        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code for you to work with. The idea is to set an `OnClickListener` for your `ImageButton`, and in that `OnClickListener` create an `Intent` to go to your new `Activity`, then call `startActivity(intent)`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_01);
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    final Context context = this;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListner(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: But when I try to run the emulator says me error: ';' expected.